# Still sort of confused about Big O notation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

So I've been trying to understand Big O notation as well as I can, but there are still some things I'm confused about. So I keep reading that if something is O(n), it *usually* is referring to the worst-case of an algorithm, *but that it doesn't necessarily have to refer to the worst case scenario*, which is why we can say the best-case of insertion sort for example is O(n). However, I can't really make sense of what that means. I know that if the worst-case is O(n^2), it means that the function that represents the algorithm in its worst case grows no faster than n^2 (there is an upper bound). But if you have O(n) as the best case, how should I read that as? In the best case, the algorithm grows no faster than n? What I picture is a graph with n as the upper bound, like

[image]

If the best case scenario of an algorithm is O(n), then n is the upper bound of how fast the operations of the algorithm grow in the best case, so they cannot grow faster than n...but wouldn't that mean that they *can* grow as fast as O(log n) or O(1), since they are below the upper bound? That wouldn't make sense though, because O(log n) or O(1) is a better scenario than O(n), so O(n) WOULDN'T be the best case? I'm so lost lol

Comment: Just as worst cases are given in terms of upper bounds, best cases are given in terms of lower bounds, which are specified with big-omega notation. A best case of Ω(n) would mean that the function is always at least linear, but could grow faster.

Comment: That graph doesn't really do justice to the `O()` curves. Extend it out to about x=1000 for a better view...

Comment: Big-O/Big-Theta/Big-Omega is independent of worst-case/average-case/best-case. I'll try to post an answer that explains this in detail, stay tuned.

Comment: Read @Mehrdad's post carefully.  People get this wrong all  the time.  Big-O is all about _functions_.  _You_ get to decide what function you're describing: worst case, average case, amortized, etc. and also of what: comparisons, run time on a specific machcine model (real RAM, etc.), storage space.  It's all about assumptions and definitions.  Lot's of material on the web omits these, which is no doubt what's causing your confusion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Big-O, Big-Θ, Big-Ω are independent from worst-case, average-case, and best-case.

The notation f(n) = O(g(n)) means f(n) grows *no more quickly than some constant multiple of g(n)*.
The notation f(n) = Ω(g(n)) means f(n) grows *no more slowly than some constant multiple of g(n)*.
The notation f(n) = Θ(g(n)) means both of the above are true.

Note that f(n) here may represent the best-case, worst-case, or "average"-case running time of a program with input size n.
Furthermore, "average" can have many meanings: it can mean the *average input* or the *average input size* ("expected" time), or it can mean *in the long run* (amortized time), or both, or something else.

Often, people are interested in the *worst-case* running time of a program, *amortized over the running time of the entire program* (so if something costs *n* initially but only costs 1 time for the next *n* elements, it averages out to a cost of 2 per element). The most useful thing to measure here is the *least upper bound* on the worst-case time; so, typically, when you see someone asking for the Big-O of a program, this is what they're looking for.

Similarly, to prove a problem is inherently difficult, people might try to show that the *worst-case* (or perhaps average-case) running time is *at least* a certain amount (for example, exponential).
You'd use Big-Ω notation for these, because you're looking for lower bounds on these.

However, there is no special relationship between worst-case and Big-O, or best-case and Big-Ω.
Both can be used for either, it's just that one of them is more typical than the other.

So, upper-bounding the *best* case isn't terribly useful. Yes, if the algorithm *always* takes O(n) time, then you can say it's O(n) in the best case, as well as on average, as well as the worst case. That's a perfectly fine statement, except *the best case* is usually very trivial and hence not interesting in itself.

Furthermore, note that f(n) = n = O(n<sup>2</sup>) -- this is technically correct, because f grows more slowly than n<sup>2</sup>, but it is *not useful* because it is not the *least* upper bound -- there's a very obvious upper bound that's more useful than this one, namely O(n). So yes, you're perfectly welcome to say the best/worst/average-case running time of a program is O(n!). That's mathematically perfectly correct. It's just useless, because when people ask for Big-O they're interested in the *least* upper bound, not just a random upper bound.

It's also worth noting that *it may simply be insufficient* to describe the running-time of a program as f(n). *The running time often depends on the input itself, not just its size*.  For example, it may be that *even* queries are trivially easy to answer, whereas *odd* queries take a long time to answer.
In that case, you can't just give *f* as a function of *n* -- it would depend on other variables as well.  In the end, remember that this is just a set of mathematical tools; it's your job to figure out how to apply it to your program and to figure out *what's an interesting thing to measure*. Using tools in a useful manner needs some creativity, and math is no exception.

Answer (score 3):

Informally speaking, *best case has O(n) complexity* means that when the input meets 
certain conditions (i.e. is best for the algorithm performed), then the count of 
operations performed in that best case, is linear with respect to n (e.g. is 1n or 1.5n or 5n). 
So if the best case is O(n), usually this means that in the best case *it is exactly linear* 
with respect to n (i.e. asymptotically no smaller and no bigger than that) - see (1). Of course, 
if in the best case that same algorithm can be proven to perform at most c * log N operations 
(where  c is some constant), then this algorithm's best case complexity would be informally 
denoted as O(log N) and not as O(N) and people would say it is O(log N) in its best case.

Formally speaking, *"the algorithm's best case complexity is O(f(n))"* 
is an informal and wrong way of saying that *"the algorithm's complexity 
is Ω(f(n))"* (in the sense of the Knuth definition - see (2)).

See also:

(1) [Wikipedia "Family of Bachmann-Landau notations"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)

(2) [Knuth's paper "Big Omicron and Big Omega and Big Theta"](http://www.phil.uu.nl/datastructuren/10-11/knuth_big_omicron.pdf)

(3) 
[Big Omega notation - what is f = Ω(g)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716291/big-omega-notation-what-is-f-g)

(4)
[What is the difference between Θ(n) and O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-on)

(5)
[What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o/487278)

Comment: It seems to me that saying an alg. is best-case O(n) is an informal (and wrong) way of saying that the alg. is Omega(n). And by that I want to say that I think your answer would be even better if you mentioned Omega(n).

Comment: @jkbkot OK, which one of the two definitions of Big Omega do you mean? From Wikipedia there're two definitions: "The first one (chronologically) is used in analytic number theory, and the other one in computational complexity theory. When the two subjects meet, this situation is bound to generate confusion." I guess I am from the confused ones. I guess you meant the Knuth definition.

Comment: I really meant Omega because Omega describes a lower bound. O() describes an upper bound. Theta is when the two meet, so I'd find it a bit difficult to discuss Theta to answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to think of `O()` as about ratios than about bounds. It is defined as bounds, and so that is a valid way to think of it, but it seems a bit more useful to think about "if I double the number/size of inputs to my algorithm, does my processing time double (`O(n)`), quadruple (`O(n^2)`), etc...". Thinking about it that way makes it a little bit less abstract - at least to me...

Comment: No offense but the OP's question is about O(f(n)) in the best case context.